# Emitting an expression on update

Tags: angular

I have an expression (model) which is set through property binding from a datepicker. This expression I want to emit to the parent component with EventEmitter. What is the best way to listen to updates of the expression? Or is there a better way of emitting it?

```
@Output() date: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
model: string;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use getter and setter to do whatever you want when your model value changes.

```
@Output() date: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
_model: string;
get model(): string {
    return _model;
}
set model(value: string) {
    this._model = value;
    date.emit("WhateverYouWant");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can emit your model whenever you want using the emit function on EventEmitter. This is probably most relevant once you have set the value of model you want to emit:

```
date.emit(model);
```

If you then want to listen to this event you just do the following in your parent component template:

```
<my-child-component (date)="myFunction(event)"></my-child-component>
```

where myFunction(event) is a method in your ts file which you can use to access the model you emitted from the child component:

```
myFunction(model: string) {
  whatever you want
}
```